# Mostrar Imagem de Carregamento no Meio da Tela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho um formulário e ao digitar o CEP mostro um gif de loading enquanto carrego a rua, o bairro e etc.

O problema é que conforme o usuário vai descendo o formulário, o gif do carregamento não aparece, pois fica "preso" na parte de cima do formulário dando a impressão que o site está travado.

Gostaria que a imagem de carregamento acompanhe a tela, aparecendo exatamente no meio da tela, para que o usuário veja que está acontecendo um carregamento.

Aceito outras sugestões que se adequem ao caso.

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<div id="loader" class="loader" style="display: none">
     <img width="35px" height="35px" src="{{ asset('img/ajax-loader.gif') }}" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="loader">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <label for="cep">CEP:</label>
     <input type="text" id="cep" name="cep" class="form-control important" value="{{ old('cep') }}">
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$('#cep').on('blur', function(){
    var f_empresa_nova = $('#f_empresa_nova').serializeArray();
    var url = "/cep";
    loader('on');
    $.post(url, f_empresa_nova, function(data){
        loader('off');
        $('#logradouro').val(data.logradouro);
        $('#bairro').val(data.bairro);
        $('#cidade').val(data.cidade);
        $('#uf').val(data.uf);
        $('#cep').removeClass();
        $('#cep').addClass("form-control required");
    });
});
```

Comment: Caso o block-ui nao atender, posta seu codigo no jsfiddler que fazemos juntos isso.

Comment: Oq vc quer fazer é algo assim? http://jsfiddle.net/k67Zk/

Comment: Você quer o loading fique no centro e bloqueie a tela até carregar?

Comment: isso mesmo @Bia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, eu ia postar um codigo para fazer na mão mas nem eu faço mais, muito esforco para pouca coisa.

Aconselho vc usar o componente [block-ui](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).
Veja esse [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/dAKQX/) .

```js
//UI block
window.onload = function() {
    
    var blockUI = document.createElement("div");
    blockUI.setAttribute("id", "blocker");
    blockUI.innerHTML = '<div>Loading...<img src="http://www.socialups.com/static/images/fbinventory/ajax_loader.gif"></div>'
    document.body.appendChild(blockUI);
    
    
    var cover = document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = "none";
    
    var btn = document.getElementById("bloc");
    
    btn.onclick = block;
    
    function block()
    {
        document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = "";
        setTimeout(function()
        {
        document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = "none";
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

```css
#blocker
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: auto;
}
    #blocker div
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 5em;
        height: 2em;
        margin: -1em 0 0 -2.5em;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    #blocker img
    {
        position: relative;
        top: -55px;
        left: 15%;
    }
```

```html
<button id="bloc">Block UI</button>
```

Comment: blz, vou dar uma olhada aqui.

Comment: Qlq duvida te ajudo a implementar.

Comment: é, eu não consegui entender muito bem como faria pra colocar aqui, vou editar minha pergunta com o que eu uso atualmente, se der pra me ajudar seria otimo.

Comment: poste seu codigo no jsfiddler para gente codar juntos

Comment: consegui implementar aqui @RBoschini, obrigado!