# Gif de carregamento enquanto função executa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso colocar um gif de carregamento enquanto uma função executa. A função simplesmente troca o valor de vários produtos, quando o usuário clicar no botão o gif deve aparecer e quando os inputs ficarem preenchidos ele deve sumir.

```
$("#aumentar").click(function(){
  var ajuste = $("#valor").val();
  $('.gif').css('display','block');
  trocaValoresInputs(ajusteDeValor);
  $('.gif').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: tem várias peguntas parecidas no site como essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/275156/57220 e essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107933/57220

Answer (score 0):

Sua idéia está correta, ao começar o processo vc deve exibir o elemento de loading e ao terminar o processo, você deve esconde-lo, se atente apenas para a função trocaValoresInputs deve ser sincrona, se for assincrona ela vai continuar executando por debaixo dos panos e vai esconder o loading antes do que você espera.